# SBS 2011 Standard: Exchange Database Size Limit?

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

Exchange 2010 Standard's limit is [1024 GB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232092.aspx); is this the same for SBS 2011 Standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default limit is 1TB but you can change it.  See this site for more info http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2011/03/20/exchange-2010-default-database-size.aspx